# Calculating the total in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

*OP, please replace this text with a detailed description of your problem. Your code is below.*

---

I used `document.getElementById` but the math is not working. I need total to be calculated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title></title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function a()
{

var q = document.getElementById('ad').value;
document.getElementById('s').value=q  + q;
}

</script>
</head>
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("form1", $con);


error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$nam=$_GET['msg'];

 $row=mysql_query("select * from inv where Name='$nam'");
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($row))
{ 
$Name=$row1['Name'];
  $Address =$row1['Address'];
  $City=$row1['City'];
    $Pincode=$row1['Pincode'];
  $No=$row1['No'];
  $Date=$row1['Date'];
  $DCNo=$row1['DCNo'];
  $DcDate=$row1['DcDate'];
  $YourOrderNo=$row1['YourOrderNo'];
  $OrderDate=$row1['OrderDate'];
  $VendorCode=$row1['VendorCode'];
  $SNo=$row1['SNo'];
  $descofgoods=$row1['descofgoods'];
  $Qty=$row1['Qty'];
  $Rate=$row1['Rate'];
  $Amount=$row1['Amount'];
}

?>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="846" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="411" height="113">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="412">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="846" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td height="38">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="846" border="0">

    <tr>
      <td width="390" rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="92" height="35">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="136"><?php echo $No;?></td>
      <td width="36">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="170"><?php echo $Date;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="37">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><?php echo $DCNo;?></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><?php echo $DcDate;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="34">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><?php echo $YourOrderNo;?></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><?php echo $OrderDate;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="29">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><?php echo $VendorCode;?></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="845" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td height="38">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="34">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="457">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="104">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="79">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="149">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
      <?php $i=1;  
    $row=mysql_query("select * from inv where Name='$nam'");
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($row))
{ 
$descofgoods=$row1['descofgoods'];
  $Qty=$row1['Qty'];
  $Rate=$row1['Rate'];
  $Amount=$row1['Amount'];
?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $descofgoods;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $Qty;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $Rate;?></td>
              <td><input name="Amount" type = "text" id ="ad" value="<?php echo $Amount;?>" /></td>
            </tr>   


    <?php  $i++;} ?>
  </table>
  <table width="844" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="495" height="1065">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="textfield2" />        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td>
      <td width="191">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="144"><input type="text" name="tot" id="s" onclick="a()"; /></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: @DAFFODIL Please put more effort into your questions. 1) Please post code **here**, not on a 3rd party site. This question will be completely worthless for other people in a month when the code gets removed from dpaste. 2) Concentrate on the relevant parts of the code. 3) Describe the problem. "Is nt working" is nt a problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use **document.getElementById('ad')** since that would only return you one single element (which works if only one row is returned by the SQL query).

Instead use **document.getElementsByName('Amount')** (note that the parameter is case-sensitive) since that will return you an array of multiple elements with the name **Amount** that you can iterate over and compute the total.

You'll need to change your Javascript function a(). see below.

```
function a()
{
    var q = document.getElementsByName('Amount');
    var count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < q.length; i++)
        count += parseInt(q[i].value,10);
    document.getElementById('s').value = count;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are probably getting the strings concatenated together, therefore getting `11` from `1 + 1`. Try using `parseInt()` to convert the String to a Number, as follows:

```
var q = parseInt(document.getElementById('ad').value, 10);
document.getElementById('s').value = q + q;
```

---

**UPDATE:** As CMS noted in another answer, you are also generating multiple elements with the same ID, which is invalid, and apart from that `getElementById()` will return only one element. Check out [CMS' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917928/calculating-the-total-in-javascript/2918041#2918041) for one approach to tackle this problem.

In addition, note that if you are adding decimal numbers together, you cannot use `parseInt()` as suggested above. You could use `parseFloat()` or the unary `+` operator to convert the String to a Number. Nevertheless you have to be [careful with floating point arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken).

Comment: Seems that the OP needs to sum monetary amounts, `parseFloat` or the unary plus operator would be a better option than `parseInt`.

Comment: @CMS: Good point. +1 [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917928/calculating-the-total-in-javascript/2918041#2918041) for the in depth analysis. I didn't notice the multiple input elements with the same id. Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

Aside the type conversion issue that others have addressed, by looking at your code, I see are some issues:

1. You are generating invalid markup, by creating multiple `input` elements with the same id (`id="ad"`) within your loop.
2. `document.getElementById` returns only *one* element.

I would recommend you to put a `class` name to identify the `input` elements you want to sum:

```
...
<td>
  <input class="amount" type="text" value="<?php echo $Amount;?>" />
</td>
...
```

Then you will be able to do it by this:

```
function getTotal() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
      el, total = 0;

  for (var i = 0, n = inputs.length; i < n; i++) {
    el = inputs[i];
    if (el.className == "amount") {
      total += +el.value; // using the unary plus operator to convert to Number
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('s').value = total;
}
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/oyuru3/edit).

Answer (score 1):

I see you have:

```
id ="ad" value="<?php echo $Amount;?>"
```

Make sure that a num is bieng echoed as a value.

if that doesnt work and you see that the value echoed is clearly a num, try forcing it by using:

```
var q = document.getElementById('ad').value * 1;
```

Comment: var q = document.getElementById('ad').value - 0; would work too. parseInt(string, radix) is the probably the proper way to do it though.